# Android C2DM help needed

Tags: android, android-c2dm

http://www.markmelive.com/2011/04/android-c2dm-server-and-client-implementation-working/#comment-1482 seems to be a great example of how to set up C2DM based on the code from the JumpNote C2DM sample app but I'm stumped with a couple of lines of code

In the C2DMReceiver class the example has the following method

```
//   @Override  
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
        super.onHandleIntentRecieved(context, intent);  
    }
```

Neither of those (onReceive and onHandleIntentRecieved) methods exist in the C2MBaseReceiver from which this class descends (imported from the jump note app) and I'm not certain how to progress from here

What I really need is some serious hand holding to implement C2DM and sync adapters as I've been struggling with this for 2 weeks now.
I would be really grateful if someone could hold my hand and guide me through this whole process from the android side . I am fine with my web server app side of things and I did manage to get registrations working with C2DM using a different approach but there are other issues I'm facing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stackoverflow is a Q&A site. We're all happy to help out with answers to questions, but this isn't really a question. I suggest you zero in on a specific issue, and ask a question about that. Then post other questions about other issues.

This is the best tutorial and sample code I've seen for C2DM. I used it, and the Google docs, and my implementation works fine.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

Comment: I've seen that tutorial and it's what got me started. Thanks for the reply and I'll have another look at it.

Comment: @ Ollie:Hey Ollie that's g8 if u have successfully implemented the C2DM in your android application.When i am trying to implement in my android application i am getting data in payload as null. I have checked the above link. I have used PHP server as an application server. If u are having demo for C2DM can u upload at somewhere or u can mail me on sumant4943@gmail.com. Thanks for help....